# How to get the id of the foreign object?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a List class which has many `ListItem`s. How could I write a method into the `ListItem` class which could return the id of the List it is belonging to?

I haven't found any other solution but loading the List from the database and get the id from that object. Which is stupid since the data is already in the `ListItem` object. I just don't know how to get it.

My `ListItem` class looks like this (I didn't write all the setters and getters).

```
public class ListItem {

  @DatabaseField(columnName = Contract.ListItem._ID, generatedId = true)
  @DefaultSortOrder
  private long id;

  @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = Contract.ListItem.LIST)
  private List list;

  public ListItem() {
  }

  public List getList() {
    return this.list;
  }
}
```

`Contract.ListItem.LIST` returns `"list_id"`.

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  Why doesn't `listItem.getList().getId()` work?

Comment: Well.. It works. I forgot that `getList()` doesn't automatically query the database.